# Vue.js Interfaces for Components

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I currently am working on a vue.js project, where i am getting a json response which has a structure like this:

```
"fields": 
    [
        {
            "type": "A",
            "propsA": "foo"
        },
        {
            "type": "A",
            "propsA": "foo"
        },
        {
            "type": "B",
            "propsB": "bar"
        },
        {
            "type": "C",
            "propsC": "bla"
        },
    ]
```

My system should be able to recognise each type in the fields and then show a certain display for their properties. This should be done with using a Vue.js-Component for each type.

After some researching I faced the following problem: I wanted to create a way you could load those components dynamically; If a new field with `"type": "C" ...` is in the response I want to
simply be able to write a new Component "C" for how it should be display and then something like a component-manager should be able to load the said component and write the data into the template.

Has someone faced the a similar challenge before and would be willing to share the way this could work with me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this may provide some insight on a possible strategy. I would recommend registering each of your possible components globally (or wherever you think you'll use them) and using the [`:is` special attribute](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#is) to dynamically load components.

Once you have your components registered, you can loop though the list of incoming fields, set the `:is` attribute to the type, and set a property to all other incoming information. This will result in the correct component being provided with its corresponding information.

```js
const A = {
  props: ['data'],
  template: `
    <div>
      <p>This is coming from the A component</p>
      <p>{{ data.text }}</p>
    </div>
  `
}

const B = {
  props: ['data'],
  template: `
    <div>
      <p>This is coming from the B component</p>
      <p>{{ data.text }}</p>
    </div>
  `
}

const C = {
  props: ['data'],
  template: `
    <div>
      <p>This is coming from the C component</p>
      <p>{{ data.text }}</p>
    </div>
  `
}

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
    'A': A,
    'B': B,
    'C': C
  },
  data: {
    fields:  [{
      type: "A",
      data: {
        text: "This is coming from the A data!"
      }
    }, {
      type: "A",
      data: {
        text: "This is coming from the A data!"
      }
    }, {
      type: "B",
      data: {
        text: "This is coming from the B data!"
      }
    }, {
      type: "C",
      data: {
        text: "This is coming from the C data"
      }
    }]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div 
    v-for="(item, key) in fields"
    :is="item.type"
    :data="item.data"
    :key="key"
  ></div>
</div>
```

Let me know if I missed anything or if you would like anything explained further.

---

#### Edit:

Now that I look at how the other properties are provided, you could probably just send the entire object rather than sending a specific object that contained the non-type information.

```
fields:  [{
  type: "A",
  textA: "This is coming from the A data!"
}, {
  type: "A",
  textA: "This is coming from the A data!"
}, {
  type: "B",
  textB: "This is coming from the B data!"
}, {
  type: "C",
  textC: "This is coming from the C data!"
}]

<div 
  v-for="(item, key) in fields"
  :key="key"
  :is="item.type"
  :data="item"
></div>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks this was exactly what i searched for!

My solution now has a ``ComponentManager.vue`` file which loads all the other ``ComponentABC.vue`` for a specific JSON-tag. Thank you so much for your quick answer, this really did help me a lot.

Just one more question: Do you think there is a possibility that i dont have to write

```javascript
components: {
            "typeA": TypeA,
            "typeB": TypeB,
            ...
        }
```

each time a new type is added? So that my component-manager will always try to load a component for a specific type.

Comment: @Nestroy No problem! Regarding your follow up question, I've never tried it, but you could probably utilize as similar strategy to [lazy loading components](https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/async-vuejs-components/).